# How can I do a string replace only when it is preceded by a certain character with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I have a situation where I need to search a css file within PHP and replace all instances of the string 'logo.png' with whatever the client uploads. Let's say they upload 'logo.jpg' (notice the different file extension).

My problem is that the css content also contains a reference to an 'applogo.png' that I want to remain unchanged. But of course whenever I run the code below, it will change the 'applogo.png' to 'applogo.jpg':

```
$cssContent = str_replace('logo.png','logo.jpg',$cssContent);
```

How can I make sure that when I search and replace 'logo.png', that it ignores 'applogo.png'?

*There are instances where the quotes may or may not be included within the string, so including the quote is not reliable.

Any help or guidance towards resources is appreciated.

Comment: Either include the quotes in the search (and replace) string or use regexes.

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my original question. I forgot to add that there are instances where the quotes may not be there.

Comment: Can't you edit the CSS file to always include quotes ? Just wondering..

Comment: Is there any preceding characters like a `(` that can be used as a boundary?

Comment: There are instances where the reference could look like this `(logo.png)` or this `('logo.png')`, same goes for `(applogo.png)` or this `('applogo.png')`. I could have two `str_replace` that would take care of both, but is there a cleaner way? I'm not that experienced in regex

Comment: I'm bad at regex too, but I know how to read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) : `str_replace(["(logo.png)", "('logo.png')"], '(logo.jpg)', $cssContent)`

Comment: I changed the marked question. You'll need to use lookbehinds or a simple capturing group:  `(?<=\('|\()logo\.png` See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/OZCj96/1

Comment: `preg_replace('/^logo\.png/', '', $cssContent);`